# Permission to run a site-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

In my organizzation, I created an internal site with a script callable from different pages inside that reads / writes data from various spreadsheets and send mail.
For testing, I shared the site and documents with a my colleague but he can't run the scripts because appears page to request permission:
"... This script is Requesting permission to do potentially harmful operations. Only authorize the script if you truly trust the author!"
if my colleague click on "authorize" nothing happens.

I give to my colleague the link of the script (not the page that embeds the script), clicking on "authorize" he received a long email from google where it is explained that authorized the execution of the script but instead continues to not work ..

The one way to allow the execution of script is to run the script directly from the editor to grant permissions. 
I can't do it for other colleagues!!!

I'm really unhappy about this. I worked a lot on the script but now I realize that I can't do it to my colleagues for another google's big bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that uses also spreadsheet and mail service and I have not any difficulties with authorizations ...(after the red screen is approved user have full access to the app)

Are you sure there is not something else that could prevent your script to work with other users ? A document that is not shared or a call to an external api or whatever ?  All I can say is that the current procedure is far more convenient than it used to be a few month ago and that I see not bug on that just now...

Comment: permissions are only for the following listed in the red box.
Spreadsheets (Read / Write)
Send Email
Sites (Read Only)

if the user clicks on "Authorize" nothing happens.

permission is granted only if the user runs the script from editor

Comment: I agree with Serge. Please check if your colleague is not able to run the script because of other reasons. Does a simple 'hello world' script run for your colleague? If yes, then you can very well suspect stuff in your doGet() function

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with scripts in spreadsheets, new users have to run the script, authorize it, and run it again.

Comment: The Oauth approvals are handled separately